# Getting blank page with PhantomJS request

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, httprequest

I am trying to get a page of site names build.com using phantomjs like this :

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36';
page.onInitialized = function ()
{
    page.customHeaders = {
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    };
    page.viewportSize = {
        width: 1280,
        height: 1024
    };
};
page.evaluate(function () {});
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};
page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
    var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];
    if (trace && trace.length) {
        msgStack.push('TRACE:');
        trace.forEach(function(t) {
        msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
    });
  }
  console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
};
page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
      console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + ' URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
      console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};
page.onResourceTimeout = function(request) {
      console.log('Response Timeout (#' + request.id + '): ' + JSON.stringify(request));
};
page.open('https://www.build.com/millennium-lighting-rwhc17-pendant-light/s875082', function (status)
{
    if (status == 'success')
    {}
    page.render('export.png');
    fs.write('1.html', page.content, 'w');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

But am getting a blank page. Why is it so ? Am I doing something wrong here ? Please help. Am new to phantomjs world :)

Tried with different versions of phantomJS, But still same behaviour :(

Downloaded phantomJS from [this](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) link

When hitting for few times (4-5 max) am getting correct screenshot and the page, but for more than that am getting blank page.

The console output contains this :

```
Unable to load resource (#6 URL:https://www.build.com/blddstlfjwbtysftuzqdbvevbwdr.js?PID=BD9E1747-99DF-3DE1-AF48-65E96064EC7E)
Error code: 5. Description: Operation canceled
```

Also the status came out to be "fail" in contrast to "success" in 4 times.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am using 1.9.8 generally for testing. Plus the main pain point is am getting response for first 4-5 requests with same code, but after that am getting the above mentioned error. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying that you're executing the script over and over again and after 5 times, the pages stops loading? That looks like it's not a PhantomJS issue, but rather the page is detecting a DoS attacks and blocks your IP.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Can you try this code on your system (if possible) ? Because I don't think its a DoS attack detection. Noone blocks after 4 requests :(

Comment: It seems like the page detects PhantomJS.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Did u checked ? Is there any workaround ?

Comment: I did run it. There was a captcha page when I removed the user agent string setting. No idea, how this can be fixed. You could just use a different browser through Selenium and if you need it headlessly then run it with xvfb

Comment: @ArtjomB. Can you explain both ways : You could just use a different browser through Selenium and if you need it headlessly then run it with xvfb ?

Comment: No, I won't explain this further, because there are tons of examples if you search for "<your favorite language> selenium example". Xvfb can also be found through your favorite search engine, but it only works on Linux/Unix.

Comment: @ArtjomB. No this I know. Selenium driver I use with Java but what you mean by "use a different browser " is it meanining a different useragent ? As its not even working with every user agent

Comment: No, I actually mean a different browser. Selenium can drive many different browsers including Firefox and Chrome.